# Adding a MapView Programmatically

Tags: swift3, mkmapview

I am trying to add a Map View to one of my View Controllers programmatically. Here is what I have so far:

```
let mapView: MKMapView = {

        let map = MKMapView()

        map.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        map.mapType = MKMapType.standard
        map.isZoomEnabled = true
        map.isScrollEnabled = true

        return map
    }()


 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(mapView)

        //Mark: MapView

        mapView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        mapView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        mapView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        mapView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
```

However, when I load this View Controller, I get a blank white screen. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the out-of-the-box behaviour of `MKMapView`... I assume it is being displayed in the view hierarchy, but not loading any maps. Did you try to change the background color to something other than white (e.g., red)?

Comment: Yup! I tried that. This method usually works for other types of UIViews like Labels,TextField,Buttons, etc. Not sure why it does not work for maps. Thanks for your suggestion anyway!